# Как работать с параметрами функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, условия, параметры

Передо мной поставили задачу сделать функцию **generatePass** более универсальной. Таким образом, чтобы генерация пароля не могла зависеть от условий активности чекбокса.
Чтобы например применить эту функцию в другом проекте, в котором вместо чекбоксов будет что-то другое, но при этом, его функциональность должна оставаться прежней(добавление числа, спец.символа, заглавной буквы).

Мне нужно передавать как-то это в параметрах.  Только я не могу разобраться как это сделать.
У меня в голове застряли эти условия, я не могу от них избавиться.

Прошу помочь, может я неправильно понимаю поставленную задачу.

```js
let buttonPass = document.getElementById('button_pass');

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('button_pass').click();
  return;
}

buttonPass.addEventListener('click', function generatePass(num, punct, consonLow, vowLow, vowUpp) {

  let numCheckbox = document.getElementById('num_checkbox');
  let punctCheckbox = document.getElementById('punct_checkbox');
  let letLowCheckbox = document.getElementById('let_low_checkbox');
  let letUppCheckbox = document.getElementById('let_upp_checkbox');
  let lenPass = document.getElementById('len_pass');
  let blockResult = document.getElementById('block_result');

  num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  punct = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '~', '`', '}', '{', '[', ']'];
  consonLow = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  vowLow = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ];
  vowUpp = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', ];

  function shuffle() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  }
  num.sort(shuffle);
  punct.sort(shuffle);
  consonLow.sort(shuffle);
  vowLow.sort(shuffle);
  vowUpp.sort(shuffle);

  function mixArrLow(consonLow, vowLow) {
    let arrLow = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < consonLow.length; i++) {
      if (i < consonLow.length) {
        arrLow.push(consonLow[i]);
        let randVow = Math.floor(Math.random() * vowLow.length);
        arrLow.push(vowLow[randVow]);
      };
    };
    return arrLow;
  };
  let mixLow = mixArrLow(consonLow, vowLow);

  if (lenPass.value < 4 || lenPass.value > 16) {
    alert('Максимальная длина пароля: 16 | Минимальная длина пароля: 4');
    return;
  }

  let genArr = [];
  let outGen = '';
  genArr = genArr.concat(mixLow);
  genArr.length = lenPass.value;
  for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
    outGen += genArr[i];
    blockResult.innerHTML = outGen;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(outGen);
  };

  if (numCheckbox.checked) {
    let numArr = [];
    let out = '';
    numArr = numArr.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)], mixLow);
    numArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if (punctCheckbox.checked) {
    let punArr = [];
    let out = '';
    punArr = punArr.concat(punct[Math.floor(Math.random() * punct.length)], mixLow);
    punArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += punArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if (letUppCheckbox.checked) {
    let uppArr = [];
    let out = '';
    uppArr = uppArr.concat(vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random() * vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    uppArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += uppArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if (numCheckbox.checked && punctCheckbox.checked) {
    let numPun = [];
    let out = '';
    numPun = numPun.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)], punct[Math.floor(Math.random() * punct.length)], mixLow);
    numPun.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numPun[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if (punctCheckbox.checked && letUppCheckbox.checked) {
    let punUpp = [];
    let out = '';
    punUpp = punUpp.concat(punct[Math.floor(Math.random() * punct.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random() * vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    punUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += punUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if (numCheckbox.checked && letUppCheckbox.checked) {
    let numUpp = [];
    let out = '';
    numUpp = numUpp.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random() * vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    numUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if (numCheckbox.checked && punctCheckbox.checked && letUppCheckbox.checked) {
    let numPunUpp = [];
    let outNPU = '';
    numPunUpp = numPunUpp.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length)], punct[Math.floor(Math.random() * punct.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random() * vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    numPunUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      outNPU += numPunUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = outNPU;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(outNPU);
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Генератор паролей</h2>
    <div class="block"><span>Длина пароля</span><input type="number" max="16" min="4" value="10" id="len_pass"></div>
    <div class="block"><span>Добавить число</span><input type="checkbox" id="num_checkbox"></div>
    <div class="block"><span>Добавить специ.символ</span><input type="checkbox" id="punct_checkbox"></div>
    <div class="block"><span>Добавить заглавную букву</span><input type="checkbox" id="let_upp_checkbox"></div>
    <button id="button_pass">Сгенерировать пароль</button>
    <div id="block_result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой вариант. В объект passwordParam необходимо помещать нужные параметры для формирования пароля. Например `addNum = true`(значит в пароль нужно добавить число). Объект формируется, обрабатывая получаемые с формы данные. При использовании кнопок он проверяет кнопки каких параметров нажаты, а при использовании выпадающих списков - какие варианты выбраны. Главное в блоке с условием прописать атрибут `data-pas-param="addNum"`, `"addSymbol"` или "`addUppLetter`", вызывать функцию `test`, передав ей идентификатор используемого элемента, а в самой функции прописать обработку входящего условия (в моем варианте - нажатие кнопки или выбор выпадающего списка)

В вашем коде я добавил:

- Объявление объекта `passwordParam`
- Функцию `test`
- Изменил условия c например `if (numCheckbox.checked..` на `if(passwordParam.addNum==true...`

```js
let buttonPass = document.getElementById('button_pass'),
    passwordParam = {}


function test(id){
  let element =  document.getElementById(id),
        param = element.closest('.block').getAttribute('data-pas-param')
  if(element.getAttribute('type')=='button'){
    element.classList.contains('click')?passwordParam[param] = true:delete passwordParam[param]
  }
  else if(element.getAttribute('type')=='checkbox'){
    element.checked==true?passwordParam[param] = true:delete passwordParam[param]
  }
  else{
    element.value==1?passwordParam[param] = true:delete passwordParam[param]
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('button_pass').click();
  return;
}

buttonPass.addEventListener('click', function generatePass(num, punct, consonLow, vowLow, vowUpp) {

  let numCheckbox = document.getElementById('num_checkbox');
  let punctCheckbox = document.getElementById('punct_checkbox');
  let letLowCheckbox = document.getElementById('let_low_checkbox');
  let letUppCheckbox = document.getElementById('let_upp_checkbox');
  let lenPass = document.getElementById('len_pass');
  let blockResult = document.getElementById('block_result');

  num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  punct = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '~', '`', '}', '{', '[', ']'];
  consonLow = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  vowLow= ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u',];
  vowUpp= ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U',];

  function shuffle() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  }
  num.sort(shuffle);
  punct.sort(shuffle);
  consonLow.sort(shuffle);
  vowLow.sort(shuffle);
  vowUpp.sort(shuffle);

  function mixArrLow(consonLow, vowLow) {
  let arrLow = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < consonLow.length; i++) {
    if (i < consonLow.length) {
      arrLow.push(consonLow[i]);
      let randVow = Math.floor(Math.random() * vowLow.length);
      arrLow.push(vowLow[randVow]);
    };
  };
  return arrLow;
  };
  let mixLow = mixArrLow(consonLow, vowLow);

  if (lenPass.value < 4 || lenPass.value > 16) {
    alert('Максимальная длина пароля: 16 | Минимальная длина пароля: 4');
  return;
  }

  let genArr = [];
    let outGen = '';
    genArr = genArr.concat(mixLow);
    genArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      outGen += genArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = outGen;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(outGen);
    };

  //if (numCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addNum==true){
    let numArr = [];
    let out = '';
    numArr = numArr.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], mixLow);
    numArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  //if (punctCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addSymbol==true){
    let punArr = [];
    let out = '';
    punArr = punArr.concat(punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], mixLow);
    punArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += punArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  //if (letUppCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addUppLetter==true){
    let uppArr = [];
    let out = '';
    uppArr = uppArr.concat(vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    uppArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += uppArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  //if (numCheckbox.checked && punctCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addNum==true&&passwordParam.addSymbol==true){
    let numPun = [];
    let out = '';
    numPun = numPun.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], mixLow);
    numPun.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numPun[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };
  
  //if (punctCheckbox.checked && letUppCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addSymbol==true&&passwordParam.addUppLetter==true){
    let punUpp = [];
    let out = '';
    punUpp = punUpp.concat(punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    punUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += punUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  //if (numCheckbox.checked && letUppCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addUppLetter==true&&passwordParam.addNum==true){
    let numUpp = [];
    let out = '';
    numUpp = numUpp.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    numUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  //if (numCheckbox.checked && punctCheckbox.checked && letUppCheckbox.checked) {
  if(passwordParam.addUppLetter==true&&passwordParam.addNum==true&&passwordParam.addSymbol==true){
    let numPunUpp = [];
    let outNPU = '';
    numPunUpp = numPunUpp.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    numPunUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      outNPU += numPunUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = outNPU;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(outNPU);
    };
  };
});
```

```css
button.click{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
#button_pass{
  margin: 10px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
}
.container>div{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Генератор паролей</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Генератор паролей</h2>
    <div class="block"><span>Длина пароля</span><input type="number" max="16" min="4" value="10" id="len_pass"></div>
    <div>ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ
      
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addNum"><span>Добавить число</span><input type="checkbox" id="num_checkbox" onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))"></div>
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addSymbol"><span>Добавить специ.символ</span><input type="checkbox" id="punct_checkbox" onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))"></div>
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addUppLetter"><span>Добавить заглавную букву</span><input type="checkbox" id="let_upp_checkbox" onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))"></div>
    </div>
    <div>ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addNum"><button type="button" id="num_checkbox_second" onclick="
      this.classList.toggle('click')
      test(this.getAttribute('id'))
      ">добавить число</button></div>
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addSymbol"><button type="button" id="addSymbol_second" onclick="
      this.classList.toggle('click')
      test(this.getAttribute('id'))
      ">добавить спец. символ</button></div>
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addUppLetter"><button type="button" id="addUppLetter_second" onclick="
      this.classList.toggle('click')
      test(this.getAttribute('id'))
      ">Добавить заглавную букву</button></div>
    </div>
    <div>ТРЕТИЙ ВАРИАНТ
       <div class="block" data-pas-param="addNum"><label for="num_checkbox_third">Добавить цифру?<select id="num_checkbox_third" onchange="
      test(this.getAttribute('id'))
      ">
            <option value="1">ДА</option>
            <option value="0" selected>НЕТ</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addSymbol"><label for="addSymbol_third">Добавить спец.символ?<select id="addSymbol_third" onchange="
      test(this.getAttribute('id'))
      ">
            <option value="1">ДА</option>
            <option value="0" selected>НЕТ</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="block" data-pas-param="addUppLetter"><label for="addUppLetter_third">Добавить заглавную букву?<select id="addUppLetter_third" onchange="
      test(this.getAttribute('id'))
      ">
            <option value="1">ДА</option>
            <option value="0" selected>НЕТ</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <button id="button_pass">Сгенерировать пароль</button>
  <div id="block_result"></div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Кажется, это то, что мне нужно. Конечно кнопки и выпадающий список были излишними, но для наглядности, это даже лучше, поэтому БЛАГОДАРЮ ЗА ПОМОЩЬ. Жаль только я все равно не понимаю как в совокупности все это работает. Как работает **data-атрибуты**, что означает эта запись **onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))**  И как работает сама функция **test** :(

Comment: Это прямо основы, без них будет тяжело. Что такое **data-атрибуты** лучше гуглить, там лучше объяснят. **onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))** - при изменении элемента (input'a или select'a) вызывается функция `test()`, куда единственным аргументом передается идентификатор изменяемого элемента. В функции `test()` определяется что за элемент меняется и в зависимости от этого в объект `passwordParam` передается нужное значение (добавить число, символ и т.д). Если нажимается _кнопка_ проверяется нажата ли она или отжата, если меняется _чекбокс_ - выбран он или нет.

Comment: https://mr-ilzur.github.io/LastGeneratePassword/ Вот я сейчас разделил на два файла js. Только возникла проблема он не видит функцию test. Если ее вместе с passwordParam переместить в функцию generatePass, тогда не работает запись onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id')). Не знаю как быть.