# Как оформить класс JS

Tags: javascript, ооп, функции, классы

Всем привет помогите оформить функцию **generatePass** как класс.

Второстепенные вопросы:

- При нажатии на кнопку, вызов класса будет работать так же, как если бы я вызывал функцию? То есть если этот класс отельным js файлом сделаю и попытаюсь затем его импортировать? Это будет работать так же, как с функцией??
- При всем при этом, я сейчас даже как функцию **generatePass** не могу импортировать, потому что в файле app.js он не будет видеть функцию **test**, а если поместить **test** и **passwordParam** внутрь **generatePass**, тогда не видны **onchange** указанные в html. Об этой проблеме я писал тоже в комментариях полученного ответа [Как работать с параметрами функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268212/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8). Как решить эту проблему я не разобрался.

Прошу помочь.

```
let buttonPass = document.getElementById('button_pass');

  let passwordParam = {};

  // Функция которая магическим образом отслеживает изменения элемента инпута и в зависимости от этого в объект passwordParam передает нужное значение.
  function test(id){
  let element =  document.getElementById(id),
        param = element.closest('.block').getAttribute('data-pas-param')
  if(element.getAttribute('type')=='checkbox'){
    element.checked==true?passwordParam[param] = true:delete passwordParam[param]
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('button_pass').click();
  return;
}

buttonPass.addEventListener('click', function generatePass(num, punct, consonLow, vowLow, vowUpp) {

  let numCheckbox = document.getElementById('num_checkbox');
  let punctCheckbox = document.getElementById('punct_checkbox');
  let letLowCheckbox = document.getElementById('let_low_checkbox');
  let letUppCheckbox = document.getElementById('let_upp_checkbox');
  let lenPass = document.getElementById('len_pass');
  let blockResult = document.getElementById('block_result');

  num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  punct = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '~', '`', '}', '{', '[', ']'];
  consonLow = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  vowLow= ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u',];
  vowUpp= ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U',];

  // Заранее перемешиваю элементы в каждом из указанных массивов
  function shuffle() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  }
  num.sort(shuffle);
  punct.sort(shuffle);
  consonLow.sort(shuffle);
  vowLow.sort(shuffle);
  vowUpp.sort(shuffle);

  // Чередую согласные и гласные буквы для того чтобы пароль стал читаемым(удобынм)
  function mixArrLow(consonLow, vowLow) {
  let arrLow = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < consonLow.length; i++) {
    if (i < consonLow.length) {
      arrLow.push(consonLow[i]);
      let randVow = Math.floor(Math.random() * vowLow.length);
      arrLow.push(vowLow[randVow]);
    };
  };
  return arrLow;
  };
  let mixLow = mixArrLow(consonLow, vowLow);

  if (lenPass.value < 4 || lenPass.value > 16) {
    alert('Максимальная длина пароля: 16 | Минимальная длина пароля: 4');
  return;
  }
  // Генерирация пароля
  let genArr = [];
    let outGen = '';
    genArr = genArr.concat(mixLow);
    genArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      outGen += genArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = outGen;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(outGen);
    };

  /* Условия для генерации пароля с дополнительными опциями(добавление числа, спец.символа, заглавной буквы) */
  if(passwordParam.addNum == true){
    let numArr = [];
    let out = '';
    numArr = numArr.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], mixLow);
    numArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if(passwordParam.addSymbol == true){
    let punArr = [];
    let out = '';
    punArr = punArr.concat(punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], mixLow);
    punArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += punArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if(passwordParam.addUppLetter == true){
    let uppArr = [];
    let out = '';
    uppArr = uppArr.concat(vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    uppArr.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += uppArr[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if(passwordParam.addNum == true&&passwordParam.addSymbol == true){
    let numPun = [];
    let out = '';
    numPun = numPun.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], mixLow);
    numPun.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numPun[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if(passwordParam.addSymbol == true&&passwordParam.addUppLetter == true){
    let punUpp = [];
    let out = '';
    punUpp = punUpp.concat(punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    punUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += punUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if(passwordParam.addUppLetter == true && passwordParam.addNum==true){
    let numUpp = [];
    let out = '';
    numUpp = numUpp.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    numUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      out += numUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = out;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(out);
    };
  };

  if(passwordParam.addUppLetter == true && passwordParam.addNum == true && passwordParam.addSymbol == true){
    let numPunUpp = [];
    let outNPU = '';
    numPunUpp = numPunUpp.concat(num[Math.floor(Math.random()*num.length)], punct[Math.floor(Math.random()*punct.length)], vowUpp[Math.floor(Math.random()*vowUpp.length)], mixLow);
    numPunUpp.length = lenPass.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < lenPass.value; i++) {
      outNPU += numPunUpp[i];
      blockResult.innerHTML = outNPU;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(outNPU);
    };
  };
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Генератор паролей</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Генератор паролей</h2>
    <div class="block"><span>Длина пароля</span><input type="number" max="16" min="4" value="10" id="len_pass"></div>
    <div class="block" data-pas-param="addNum"><span>Добавить число</span><input type="checkbox" id="num_checkbox" onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))"></div>
    <div class="block" data-pas-param="addSymbol"><span>Добавить специ.символ</span><input type="checkbox" id="punct_checkbox" onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))"></div>
    <div class="block" data-pas-param="addUppLetter"><span>Добавить заглавную букву</span><input type="checkbox" id="let_upp_checkbox" onchange="test(this.getAttribute('id'))"></div>
    <button id="button_pass">Сгенерировать пароль</button>
    <div id="block_result"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уменьшите количество кода, оставив только то, что имеет *непосредственное* отношение к вопросу.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас не правильный подход к реализации функции generatePass, вы прямо в ней взаимодействуете с элементами, что как по мне не правильно. Настройки для генерации мне кажется лучше передавать через параметры, причем параметры передавать не через запятую, а объектом и в функции `Object.assign()` к "стандартным" настройкам. Так же лучше пароль вернуть из функции через return, чем записывать результат в элемент, дабы фунцию можно было применять к различным элементам.

Comment: Уменьшил количество кода. Убрал css.